# How can i scale the canvas so that my app takes up the whole screen?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, mobile

I have designed a game which scales perfecly and fits the screen on my mobile phone. However on the emulator and other devices i have tested it on it may only take up 20-50% of the screen because thoes screens were bigger. How can i scale up the canvas specific for each device?

I have tried getting the width and height of the page and changing the position of the rectangles, text , etc based on a scale where the size of my screen is divided by the size of the new screen to work out how much bigger it would be however it will not accept a decimal / double value.

I have spent hours researching this problem and have found nothing.

The code of the graphics / canvas thread is shown below:

```
  public void run() {
        while (isRunning){
            if (!holder.getSurface().isValid()){
                continue;
            }
            Canvas canvas = holder.lockCanvas();
            canvas.drawARGB(255,255,255,255);

            Paint paint = new Paint();
            paint.setTextSize(32);

            paint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
            canvas.drawText( "Next Block",525,80,paint);

            paint.setColor(NextBlock);
            canvas.drawRect(525 , 100 ,675, 250,paint);

            paint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
            canvas.drawText("Held Block",525,380,paint);

            paint.setColor(HeldBlock);
            canvas.drawRect(525,400,675,550,paint);

            paint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
            paint.setTextSize(52);
            canvas.drawText("Score",525,700,paint);
            paint.setTextSize(82);
            canvas.drawText(String.valueOf(score),525,800,paint);
            paint.setTextSize(32);

            for (int x = 0; x < 3; x++){
                for (int y= 0; y < 5; y++){
                    paint.setColor(BlocksGrid[x][y]);
                    canvas.drawRect((squareSize * x) + (gap * x) + startX, (squareSize * y) + (gap * y) + startY,(squareSize * x) + (gap * x) + startX + squareSize,(squareSize * y) + (gap * y) + startY + squareSize,paint);
                }
                paint.setColor(Color.GREEN);
                if (height[x] < 0){
                    paint.setColor(Color.RED);
                }
                canvas.drawRect((squareSize * x) + (gap * x) + startX, 870,(squareSize * x) + (gap * x) + startX + squareSize,945,paint);
            }

            holder.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);
        }
    }
```

I think this should be enough however if any more code is needed please ask.
Thank you for helping as i've been spending hours trying to fix this problem before the program is finaly finished!

Comment: I don't understand why you aren't just using layouts and already-made UI elements, like Buttons and TextViews. Android already has a system for positioning and scaling Views. Why reinvent the wheel?

Comment: Im making a game so im drawing the graphics / shapes using the canvas.

Comment: Ive just tested it using buttons and UI elements and it failed horribly but thanks for the suggestion anyway.